# How to serve two laravel apps on 1 domain?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, nginx, server

I have two laravel apps like this:

```
  - apps
      - dashboard
      - website
```

I'm trying to serve them on linux machine, I can't seem to get them to work together.
I want to have two urls like this:
https://test.example.co

https://test.example.co/dashboard

```
server {
  server_name test.example.co;
  index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

  location = / {
       root /var/www/example/apps/website;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.php;
  }

  location ~ ^/dashboard  {
       root /var/www/example/apps;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /dashboard/public/index.php;
       #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
     deny all;
  }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
server {
    if ($host = test.example.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded serving them using another subdomain, the `"/dashboard"` idea didn't work.
I hope someone can suggest the correct way to do it, I would change the accepted answer.

I have now `example.com` and `admin.example.com`.

**Nginx config as below:**

```
server {
   server_name example.com;

   index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   root /var/www/example/apps/website/public;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/example_access.log;
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/example_error.log;
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
   location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
   }

   location ~ /\.ht {
     deny all;
   }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

  listen 80 default_server;
  listen [::]:80 default_server;
  server_name example.com;
  return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And the second one is:

```
server {
   server_name admin.example.com;
   index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
   root /var/www/example/apps/dashboard/public;

   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

   access_log /var/log/nginx/example_access.log;
   error_log  /var/log/nginx/example_error.log;

   location ~ \.php$ {
     include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
     fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
   }

   location ~ /\.ht {
     deny all;
   }

   # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on /var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock
   location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri /index.php =404;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           include fastcgi_params;
   }

   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/admin.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = admin.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you tell me what is the result if you write your code like this:

```
  location ~ ^/dashboard  {
       root /var/www/example/apps/dashboard/public;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }
  location = ~ ^/ {
       root /var/www/example/apps/website/public;
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }
```

I just swap it. so it will search for the dashboard and if the user is not in dashboard, it will check the root.

Comment: Thank you, configtest fails with this unfortunately. The second part